# cant inject input in the element ID python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I've been working on automating the login process and handling 2FA on my own for this site (https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action)

While I successfully identified the element ID, I encountered difficulties with injection.

Recent updates to Selenium, Chrome, and ChromeDriver seem to have introduced some unforeseen issues.

I've previously automated numerous other sites and took a break for a few months. Upon returning, I'm finding it challenging to decipher the errors.

```
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00D04DE3+43907]
        (No symbol) [0x00C90741]
        (No symbol) [0x00B833ED]
        (No symbol) [0x00BB6760]
        (No symbol) [0x00BB6C2B]
        (No symbol) [0x00BE6F62]
        (No symbol) [0x00BD2BA4]
        (No symbol) [0x00BE55CA]
        (No symbol) [0x00BD2956]
        (No symbol) [0x00BAE17E]
        (No symbol) [0x00BAF32D]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00FB5AF9+2865305]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00FFE78B+3163435]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00FF8441+3138017]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00D8E0F0+605840]
        (No symbol) [0x00C9A64C]
        (No symbol) [0x00C96638]
        (No symbol) [0x00C9675F]
        (No symbol) [0x00C88DB7]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76397BA9+25]
        RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x775BBD3B+107]
        RtlClearBits [0x775BBCBF+191]
```

See below for my codes

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from pywinauto import keyboard as ky
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import sys

url = sys.argv[1]
username = sys.argv[2]
password = sys.argv[3]

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))


driver.get(url)
  
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) #set to 0 to wait indefinitely until the elements are presented.
username_field = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"account_name_text_field")))
username_field.send_keys('username')

ky.send_keys("VK_SHIFT down}{VK_TAB}{VK_SHIFT up}")
ky.send_keys("{ENTER}")

password_field = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"password_text_field")))
password_field.send_keys('password' + Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(4)

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Of course! Here's a refined version of your sentences:

My script currently doesn't include the 2FA component; I handle that part manually. I would greatly appreciate any immediate assistance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The element that you are finding is inside an `iframe`, you must switch first into the `iframe` before you can interact with elements inside an iframe

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[name="aid-auth-widget"]'))
```

Comment: I've incorporated the additional lines of code and also included wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15) to account for potential loading delays. Despite these adjustments, I'm still unable to locate the element.

```
driver.get('https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

# Wait for the iframe to be available and switch to it
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[name="aid-auth-widget"]'))

# Find the element by its ID and send some text to it
driver.find_element(By.ID, "account_name_text_field").send_keys('xx')```

Comment: Hi, i cant detect the iframe, i just directly key in the characters. Considered it resolved.